# XtraReport Save File

Tags: devexpress, xtrareport

I use the devexpress tool for reporting. In my Asp project, reports are opening slowly and I am looking for a solution until I find out why. Is it possible to download the report page in PDF format without opening it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [DevExpress Support Center example](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E454/) demonstrating how to print an XtraReport without showing the preview.

For DevExpress products, the Support Center is usually the best place to look first.